# How to set Neovim to use the full width of the terminal?

Tags: neovim

I am trying to resize the Neovim terminal width such that it covers full with of my terminal, but it is not covering the full width. I have also changed the background of Neovim to my background of the terminal, but nothing happened. I have also tried `:resize`, but nothing happens.

I am using Kali Linux 5.10.0 and it is the default terminal emulator of Kali Linux (Qterminal) with Neovim version 0.5.1.

[image: My Terminal screenshot]

Comment: Which terminal are you using? what is your system? Always provide the context. Otherwise, people can not help you.

Comment: I am using kali linux with its default terminal

Comment: Please add all the relevant info to your question so that people can better help you. Do not make people guess. You get a better chance of being answered.